# Puppeteer, PWA and installation?

Tags: puppeteer, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

How does Puppeteer handle PWA installation? Can I just assume that no installation will take place?

I searched for "puppeteer pwa" but could not find any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer is really a tool for testing an application. It is a headless browser and therefor would not offer any real way to test or simulate the installation flow.

The service worker should register and the initial life cycle should trigger. However it is headless, which means state is not preserved. So you are more or less doing an InCognito session each test run.

Comment: Thanks, I see no reason why state can not be preserved just because it is headless. But I guess you are right that this is the state of Puppeteer at the moment. (It is a bit surprising, though, since PWA is becoming more and more important.)

Comment: each puppeteer session is isolated. So you run it now and you simulate a user session, the next run is unprimed. That means it starts all over from scratch.